# Display router IP - CISCO Packet Manager

Tags: networking, cisco

I'm using Cisco Packet Manager for the first time.
I'd like to know how to display my router ip addresses and ports, for more clarity ...
Does someone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this command to show all configration like ports - ip - password - etc...

```
Router#show running-config
```

OR

`Router#show interfaces gigabitEthernet 0/0/0`  "You Can Change *Number Port* And Type Like *Fastethernet*"

OR

```
Router#show ip interface
```

Or Write :

```
Router#show ?
```

To See All Command Have Information :)

Answer (score 1):

In enable mod type

sh run | inc interface|ip address

that will show ip adresses, interfaces and subnet masks

and if you type show interfaces status, this will show ports and interfaces status.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
Router# show ip interface brief
```

This will list all of your interfaces (ports) on your router with their IP addresses and status.

You need to type this on Global Configuration Mode. (#)